# Using $refs with Element UI's input component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to use `ref` with `el-input` component from Element-UI? I am trying to use `$refs`to focus on the input when my Vue instance is mounted. Here is my code:

```
<div id="app">
    <el-input type="text" ref="test" placeholder="enter text"></el-input>
</div>
```

And in my Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mounted(){
    this.$refs.test.focus()
  }
})
```

The `focus` method is not working at all, even if I move `this.$refs.test.focus()` into a method and try to trigger it through an event.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `$refs` object stores *Vue components* and should be working fine. The problem is that you are attempting to invoke a `focus` method which **doesn't exist in the component**, but rather on an *input* somewhere inside the component's template.

So, to actually find the input you'd have to do something like this:

```
this.$refs.test.$el.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();
```

Not the prettiest line of code ever made, right? So, instead of calling anything in your app's `mounted` method, if you want to autofocus on the input, just do this:

```
<el-input type="text" placeholder="enter text" autofocus></el-input>
```

Comment: Hi, what if I want to set focus on some event, not on page loading. Should I use only this prettiest way, or more elegant solution exists?

Comment: I would say use whatever solves your problem. You likely have bigger things to worry about than input focus. However, if you're forced to use the "unpretty" version with some wild logic, just ask yourself if using a third-party component is still preferable to rolling your own (you can also _extend_ other components if you just need to override some bits).

Comment: the el-input component should have a focus event per the documentation:
https://element.eleme.io/?#/en-US/component/input#input-methods

Answer (score 1):

This can be also solved your problem.

```
// Focus the component, but we have to wait
// so that it will be showing first.
   this.$nextTick(() => {
       this.$refs.inputText.focus();
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use it like this

```
<div id="app">
    <el-input type="text" ref="test" placeholder="enter text"></el-input>
</div>
```

```
this.$refs.test.focus();
```

https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/input#input-methods